# How can I make my highlights span multiple pages in Google Play?

Tags: annotations, google-play-books

I highlight my books a lot. When I come to a real articulate statement that spans multiple pages sometimes I rotate the screen to reach the end of the text of interest. However even that technique fails at times. How can I select text across multiple pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 possible solutions or workarounds.

First, if viewing GPB in a web browser, it is easier to highlight text on more than one page. (I was able to do it).

Second, one workaround on a device might be to reduce text size to the smallest possible size, so that the maximum amount of text is on one book page.

Comment: great creativity to switch to a browser. I'll have to look into that interface and play with it. I think if I'm just in the mobile app interface I can highlight and make a manual note to self of the highlight's incompleteness and direct myself to extend it or merge it in the browser at a latter date. Would be nice if Google extended the notes interface to manually merge two highlights.